# Iterate through excel-like range of character combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string containing the first column in the range, and the last column in the range - e.g. `AF:IK`.

How do I check if let's say 'BX' is within the given range?

Comment: Your question is unclear what's the range of first and last columns?

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. haven't tried anything yet but based on a previous SO question i have read, OP only wanted to find if a character is within "A" to "Z". you can use the CHR value of a char and just compare if its within the chr value of A and Z. but with my case, that kind of approach wont work in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make use of `base` argument of `int` - it can get as high as to 36.

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> ht = partial(int, base=36)
>>> 
>>> r = "AF:IK"
>>> lo, hi = r.split(':')
>>> ht(lo) < ht("BX") < ht(hi)
True
>>> ht(lo) < ht("BXA") < ht(hi)
False
```

(I have created function `ht` using `functools.partial` for simpler usage.)

Comment: Using base 36, even when it's not needed to leverage the inbuilt plumbing for int was genius.

Answer (score 5):

This problem can be treated as similar to how you'd deal with base 26 maths problem. Let us treat A=1, B=2, C=3 etc. Then AA would be 1 * 26 + 1.

Let's express this in Python

```
letters = '0ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
def ordinal(values):
  result = 0
  for value in values:
     result *= 26
     result += letters.index(value)
  return result

print ordinal('A')
# should be 1

print ordinal('AA')
# should be 27

print ordinal('AF')
# should be 33

print ordinal('IK')
# should be 254

print ordinal('AF') < ordinal('BX') < ordinal('IK')
# should be True
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    def to_base26(string):
        # Convert an alphabet string base 26
        col = 0
        pos = 0
        for char in string.upper()[::-1]:
            col += 26**pos * (ord(char) - ord('A') + 1)
            pos += 1

        return col

    def check_range(lower,upper,query):
        if to_base26(lower) <= to_base26(query) and to_base26(query) <= to_base26(upper):
            print 'In Range'
        else:
            print 'Not in Range'

    check_range('AF', 'IK', 'BX')
```